# Codeigniter How to send mails but to my localhost folder

Tags: codeigniter, email, localhost

Yii2 has this feature I just want it to implement in CodeIgniter for testing purposes. I've already sent emails to gmail on one of my accounts.
Thaks.

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. Xampp, Mysql, I could mimic the activation routine writing a php to click and send like sendin an email but Yii2 has already this implemented so I thought IC would have it too. And I guess not.